# Why I can't use Iterable<Id> in SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql, query, iterable

Just interesting behaviour.

I want to write method:

```
public User[] getUsersByIds(Iterable<Id> userIds) {
    return [
        SELECT Id
        FROM User
        WHERE Id in :userIds
    ];
}
```

But during save I receive this message

> IN operator must be used with an iterable expression

I'm confused.

**Update**

More interesting that `Set<Id>` does not implement `Iterable<Id>`

Now I'm twice as confused!

Comment: Just curious, why are you using `Iterable` at all?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I use IDE that not released (and try to find some bugs and help to developers team), and just find this.

Answer (score 5):

*Why?* This question is going to be very difficult to answer. Clearly the error message could use improvement, as you have noted based on the fact that the `IN` operator accepts `Set<Id>`.

Likely this omission is just an oversight by the development team. They probably found it an unlikely use case that someone would use an `Iterable<Id>` where `List<Id>` and `Set<Id>` and even `List<SObject>` are available for use. In the abstract, use of `Iterable<Id>` here seems over-engineered. If you really want support for use of `Iterable<Id>`, you should create an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaPost) and wait a few years for it to gather dust.

---

If you're committed to using `Iterable<Id>` in your method signature, you can build the list yourself by iterating through it.

```
public List<User> getUsersByIds(Iterable<Id> userIds)
{
    List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
    Iterator<Id> i = userIds.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) ids.add(i.next());
    return [SELECT Username FROM User WHERE Id IN :ids];
}
```

Comment: The data used in a query needs to be serializable assuming the query is run in a separate process and the object that implements Iterable could easily not be.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Whereas those other supported types are known to be serializable. You should post an answer @Keith!